# MalformedURLException in application tests

Tags: testing, playframework, integration-testing, playframework-1.x

I'm working on application tests and have found an issue.
My app. has an authenticate(email, password) action inside the
Security controller and when invoked, from the login page, with a
valid e-mail and invalid password it sends me back to the login page
with an error message, located in the flash scope.

The app. test code follows :

```
Response response = 
    GET("/security/authenticate?email=validUser&password=invalid", true);
String pattern = "invalid password";
assertContentMatch(pattern, response);
```

When this code is run throws the next exception :

```
A java.lang.RuntimeException has been caught,
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /login
```

Did some research and found that :

- the exception is thrown when a new URL object creation is attempted,
  to be able for redirection, using an invalid URL. In this case no
  protocol is present
- looking at app. test in samples apps. GET is used without
  redirection, meaning that after GET only the http code is verified but
  no attempt to follow the redirection

Has anyone had this same issue also ?
Any open bug to look for info or add my 2 cents ?

Comment: Oh.. sometimes play is a pain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a description of the problem as well as code snippet to work around the issue:

https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1553-functionaltestget-with-redirect-crashes